# Maximizing Lync Window Using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, lync

I've created a script that will automatically initiate a video call with a user of my choice.

When ran, the script leaves the video call docked, with the lync video call window flashing.

How would I be able to get this window to maximize and go to full screen when the script is ran?

Thank you so much for your help.

Below is my code

```
    $assemblyPath = “C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office 2013\LyncSDK\Assemblies\Desktop\Microsoft.Lync.Model.DLL”
    Import-Module $assemblyPath


    $LyncClient = [Microsoft.Lync.Model.LyncClient]::GetClient()

    $StartVideoCallMethod = {
        $Conversation = $this.ConversationManager.AddConversation();
        $contact = $LyncClient.ContactManager.GetContactByUri("useremailhere") 
        [void]$Conversation.AddParticipant($contact);
        [void]$Conversation.Modalities['AudioVideo'].BeginConnect({}, 0);

        };
    Add-Member -InputObject $LyncClient -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name StartVideoCall -Value $StartVideoCallMethod -Force;

    # Initiate the video call
    $Conversation = $LyncClient.StartVideoCall();
```

Comment: Have a look at this function.  I have used it successfully with Lync in the past: https://gist.github.com/jakeballard/11240204

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have Lync, but something like this should work. I'm using the process name (or what I'm guessing it is) to get the MainWindowHandle for the Lync window, then sending that a command to maximize (cmd=3, see here for the full list of values: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

This code may break if more than one process matches by name, but it should get you started; if you can get the PID or some other, better unique identifier, use that. Just mess around with the output of Get-Process and you should see a number of options, and remember you can always use a Where clause to filter the output. Or of course if there's some way to get the MainWindowHandle directly from $LyncClient, even better.

```
$w = Get-Process -Name "Lync"
$Win32ShowWindowAsync = Add-Type –memberDefinition ` 
  '[DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);' `
-name “Win32ShowWindowAsync” -namespace Win32Functions –passThru

$Win32ShowWindowAsync::ShowWindowAsync($w.MainWindowHandle,3) | Out-Null
```

Comment: Eric, Thank you so much man. What I'm having issues with now is that sometimes it will maximize the lync window itself and others it will to the video call window. I tried adding a sleep time(the one you see at the end) and it works fine for when lync is already running but the exception handler in the beginning that will open lync if it isn't will cause it to work perfectly when it wants to. Its definitely cause I'm not specifying which window the process "lync". Thank you for your code though. Definitely made a difference.

Comment: Apparently my rep's not high enough to comment on your answer below (just created this account today), but if you haven't already, I'd consider examining $LyncClient (use `$LyncClient | Get-Member` to see its properties, methods, etc) and see if you can somehow pull a PID or some other unique identifier out of that. Either that or run `Get-Process` from the shell by itself while Lync is running and see if there's anything about the info returned that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Here the code that I have so far.

Still needs some tweaks to perfect it but it does the job.

Tweaks would be specifying which window to maximize as it will sometimes maximize the lync contacts window.

Code

```
$assemblyPath = “C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office 2013\LyncSDK\Assemblies\Desktop\Microsoft.Lync.Model.DLL”
    Import-Module $assemblyPath
   $exePath = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\lync.exe"

   if(!(get-process | ?{$_.path -eq $exePath})){
   Start-Process -FilePath $exePath -WindowStyle Maximized
   Start-Sleep -s 10
   }


   $LyncClient = [Microsoft.Lync.Model.LyncClient]::GetClient()

   $StartVideoCallMethod = {
       $Conversation = $this.ConversationManager.AddConversation();
       $contact = $LyncClient.ContactManager.GetContactByUri("ernesto.gomila@quirchfoods.com") 
       [void]$Conversation.AddParticipant($contact);
       [void]$Conversation.Modalities['AudioVideo'].BeginConnect({}, 0);

       };
   Add-Member -InputObject $LyncClient -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name StartVideoCall -Value $StartVideoCallMethod -Force;

   # Initiate the video call
   $Conversation = $LyncClient.StartVideoCall();

   #Maximize window
   $w = Get-Process -Name "lync"
   $Win32ShowWindowAsync = Add-Type –memberDefinition @"
   [DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow); 
   "@ -name “Win32ShowWindowAsync” -namespace Win32Functions –passThru

   Start-Sleep -s 2

   $Win32ShowWindowAsync::ShowWindowAsync($w.MainWindowHandle,3) | Out-Null
```